# How to order by using id with firstWhere in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a list of areas but ordering by id where `id = $area_id;`

I tried by using firstWhere:

```
$area_id = 31;
$areas = Area::firstWhere('id', '=', $area_id)->get()->values()->toArray();

dump($areas[0]);
```

the result of $areas[0] should be the 31th area, but is the first area

```
^ array:5 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "オアフ島"
  "area_group_id" => 1
  "created_at" => "2022-04-28T20:22:18.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2022-04-28T20:22:18.000000Z"
]
```

How can I order by "id" where `id = $area_id`?

Comment: IDs are usually unique, so you shouldn't have more than 1. `Area::firstWhere('id', '=', $area_id)` by itself should return only 1 result, so drop `->get()->values()` as they are unnecessary. A shorter way to do it would actually be `Area::find($area_id)->toArray();`

Comment: @aynber, thanks, but I don't know why by using ```Area::find($area_id)->toArray();``` returns the first area too instead the 31th Area.

Comment: What does `$area_id` contain?

Comment: @aynber just ```$area_id = 31;```

Comment: $areas = Area::firstOrFail($area_id);   what does this give you?

Comment: @Cameron SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '31' in 'field list'

Comment: Area::find($area_id);   should be looking for the column id  with a value of 31   try find or findOrFail

Comment: `id` is the PK of your table, or at least that's how it is most of the cases. Now, seen the dump of the result you posted.. shouldn't you be ordering by `area_group_id` instead? That would make more sense. If so, just do this: ```$areas = Area::where('area_group_id', $area_id)->orderByDesc('id')->get();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `orderByRaw`:

```
$areas = Area::orderByRaw('id = ? desc', [$area_id])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#orderbyraw